# Git clone bare repo without blobs

Tags: git, metadata, git-clone, git-plumbing, git-fast-import

On my git repository, I use an algorithm to assign every commit one or more unique version numbers, based on branch names and tags. I want to use this mechanism with another large repository, that I would like to clone without transferring any files.

A bare clone helps me to get rid of the working copy of the blobs, but it still downloads them from the server. A shallow clone with `--depth 1` skips most blobs, but also skips downloading the metadata for all commits except one.

Is there something like `git fast-export --no-data` which I can use on the client-side to get the graph information containing commit metadata and maybe filenames without cloning the repository from my server first? Ideally I would be able access the metadata like any other (bare, shallow) repo via `git log|show|rev-parse|show-ref`.

(I know git LFS and git Annex exist and can help reduce the size of some repos, but I can't use them on an existing repository without changing it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something like git fast-export --no-data which I can use on the client-side?

No: beside [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) (which gets metadata only for the heads of the remote repo), anything else would get the full repo history.

You would need your repo managed by a Git hosting service, like GitHub, providing an API (like the [commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)), in order to query metadata without data.

Answer (score 6):

Another Idea for this some time later: As of 2017, the pack-protocol now allows [partial clones](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone), and [there is a `--filter=blob:none` available](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt) that omits all blobs -- which should be sufficient on the server-side.

Given the current server-side implementation, sadly, this doesn't work as well as one would hope:

```
C:\Users\phi1010>git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git --filter=blob:none
Cloning into 'linux'...
warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
remote: Enumerating objects: 6876195, done.
[...]
```

Github even announced the [support of the v2 protocol and its filtering capabilities](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-11-08-git-protocol-v2-support/), but this neither works with `-c protocol.version=2`, as also stated on [Do GitHub and GitLab support git clone's --filter parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195590/do-github-and-gitlab-support-git-clones-filter-parameter)

Comment: It looks like [this is now supported by Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195590/do-github-and-gitlab-support-git-clones-filter-parameter/61964488#61964488).