# How to git clone without downloading the file objects

Tags: git

Is it possible to download all commits but not the files themselves? I want to run bisect but download the versions from the build server instead of compiling myself.

Comment: Do you mean to get the .git file only?

Comment: @ignacio Even more — only commits without trees and blobs.

Comment: Food for thought and experiments: you can try to use `git clone --filter=blob:none` but for this you need the very latest client and the very latest server that supports Git Protocol version v2. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48852630/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896644/7976758

Comment: Also my advice is to estimate the number of commits you need to run `git bisect` and use `git clone --depth` to avoid cloning the entire repository. Combine that with `--bare` or `--no-checkout`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run `git bisect` you can supply `--no-checkout` as argument if you do not want to checkout a new working tree for each iteration.

Same goes for `git clone --no-checkout` to avoid a working tree based on `HEAD` after the clone.

You can run `git bisect run my_script <arguments>` having `my_script` do whatever you want after each checkout.

In summary:

```
git clone <repo> --no-checkout
git bisect --no-checkout run my_script arguments
```

**EDIT:**

As per the suggestion of @phd, since recent versions (v2.2x) of git, "partial clones" are now supported meaning you can supply a clone "filter".

> https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone

In your case we'll use `--filter=blob:none` and `--filter=tree:0` and only retain commit-objects, but it requires the server to have a version of git installed that understands the filter or you'll get a warning:

```
warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
```

The clone command you'll want to use:

```
git clone <repo> --filter=blob:none --filter=tree:0 --no-checkout
```

Comment: That stops git creating the files on the working dir, but clone still downloads them to .git/objects

Comment: That's what he asked for, was my interpretation. "Download all the commits but not the files". He'll have the history but not the current working tree.

Comment: You cannot run git bisect (or git anything) without a .git/ folder (except ofcourse the obvious ones like git init, git clone, etc)

Comment: @phd "only commits without trees and blobs." exactly

Comment: I updated the answer with "partial-clone" syntax for blobs and trees